# Which method made the call to IWbemObjectSink::Indicate method

Tags: c++, events, process, wql

I am developing an application in `C++` using `VS2010`. In my code,I have two `WQL` queries as follows:

```
hres = pSvc->ExecNotificationQueryAsync(
        _bstr_t("WQL"), 
        _bstr_t("SELECT * " 
            "FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 "
            "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' "), 
        WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS, 
        NULL, 
        pStubSink);


     hres1 = pSvc->ExecNotificationQueryAsync(
        _bstr_t("WQL"), 
        _bstr_t("SELECT * " 
            "FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 "
            "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"), 
        WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS, 
        NULL, 
        pStubSink);
```

On cretion or deletion of processes I get its name printed into the console from the `IWbemObjectSink::Indicate` method. When the name of the process is printed, I need to know whether it was created or deleted. How will I know this? Is there some way to know which asynchronous method made the call to `Indicate` method?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__InstanceDeletionEvent and __InstanceCreationEvent are subclasses of __InstanceOperationEvent. Hence, you should be querying for instances of __InstanceOperationEvent. Then you will Get the Class from the object in your Sink Class (e.g., pStubSink) to know from which instance is being created. Look at this example to get an idea about how to handle a similar situation: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/04/04/how-can-i-monitor-for-different-types-of-events-with-just-one-script.aspx

**UPDATE1:**

__InstanceOperationEvent is superclass of: __InstanceDeletionEvent, __InstanceCreationEvent and __InstanceModificationEvent.

```
pSvc->ExecNotificationQueryAsync(
        _bstr_t("WQL"), 
        _bstr_t("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"), 
        WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS, 
        NULL, 
        pStubSink);
```

In your Indicate function:

```
Indicate(long lObjectCount,
    IWbemClassObject **apObjArray)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    for (int i = 0; i < lObjectCount; i++)
    {
        _variant_t myVariant;

        hr = apObjArray[i]->Get(_bstr_t(L"__Class"), 0, &myVariant, 0, 0);


        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {

            std::wstring classOrigin(myVariant.bstrVal);

            if (0 == classOrigin.compare(L"__InstanceDeletionEvent") )
            {

                std::wcout << L"DELETION" << std::endl;
            }
            else if (0 == classOrigin.compare(L"__InstanceCreationEvent"))
            {

                std::wcout << L"CREATION" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

myVariant will say which is the class that generated the event (read note).

**NOTE**: This will result in a constant call to your pStubSink because Processes are constantly being modificated (__InstanceModificationEvent, e.g., changes in memory/CPU).

**UPDATE2:** You could also have two different Queries (and consecuently Sink objects), one for creation and one for deletion (e.g., pStubSinkCreation, pStubSinkDeletion). In this way you (1) would know exactly when it comes from Creation and when from Deletion; and (2) would avoid to be receiving constantly the __InstanceModificationEvent.

Comment: I tried `--InstanceOperationEvent` too.But when I check the class,it outputs `Win32__Process` and nothing related to creation or deletion.

Comment: It worked fine. But according to your second suggestion, in the `Indicate` method where to  use the sink object?

Comment: What do you mean by _"in the Indicate method where to use the sink object?"_. Is it "how to know whether the event is from Creation or Deletion"? If so, you could initialize your Sink Object with a parameter to indicate so. For example, `class CSink:public IWbemObjectSink{ public: CSink(bool bCreate=true /*false=Deletion*/){mbIsCreation=bCreate;}; ~CSink(); private: bool mbIsCreation;...}`. Then, your two "pStubSink" objects: `CSink *pStubSinkCreation=new CSink(true/*Creation*/);`, and `CSink *pStubSinkDeletion=new CSink(false/*Deletion*/);`. In `Indicate`: `if(mbIsCreation){...}else{...}`.